# intellisense problem after autocompletion with Tab button in visual studio code - version:1.52.1

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

When I want to complete a Command with `tab` in vscode, after completing the Command **I don't receive any suggest from intellisense inside of parentheses or double quotes**. (It seems that after auto-completion, the text in parentheses is selected and therefore no suggestion is received.
Of course, this problem is solved after moving the text cursor, but this slows down the coding)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pQYm.gif)